# python MagicMock return value not returning tuple?

Tags: python, testing, mocking

I ran a quick test to see if something would work...

```
>>> from unittest.mock import MagicMock
>>> x = MagicMock()
>>> x.func.return_value = (0, 0)
>>> y, z = x.func()
```

seems to work like I expected, and then I try to patch something in my tests like this...

```
def setUp(self):
    """Setting up the command parameters"""
    self.command = up.Command()
    self.command.stdout = MagicMock()
    self.command.directory = '{}/../'.format(settings.BASE_DIR)
    self.command.filename = 'test_csv.csv'

@patch('module.Popen')
@patch('module.popen')
def test_download(self, m_popen, m_Popen):
    """Testing that download calls process.communicate"""
    m_Popen.communicate.return_value = (0, 0)
    self.command.download()
    m_popen.assert_called()
    m_Popen.communicate.assert_called()
```

in command.download, the code looks like this...

```
command = 'wget --directory-prefix=%s \
        https://www.phoenix.gov/OpenDataFiles/Crime%%20Stats.csv' \
        % self.directory
process = Popen(command.split(), stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
print(process.communicate())
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

my first guess would be that I was patching the wrong namespace, but when I print `communicate()` I see this...

```
<MagicMock name='mock().communicate()' id='4438712160'>
```

which means that it is getting mocked, but it is just not registering my new return value for communicate...I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call `communicate` on `process`, which is the *return value* of Popen. So you need another level in that patch call:

```
m_Popen.return_value.communicate.return_value = (0, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, seems obvious now